# Show that there is an open disk inside a subset of $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given a set $A \subset R^2$ such that $(x,y) \in A \iff x^2 + y^4 <4$.
How can I prove that there is an open disc $D((x,y),r) \subset A$ for every pair $(x,y) \in A$?
Please guide me to choose the right radius r for this disc to sit completely inside A. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only thing required of $A$?

Comment: @hardmath:Thank you, the question is edited.

Comment: @M10687: Yes, it is the only thing required of $A$.

Comment: Is your direction of implication correct? As written, the empty set satisfies your hypothesis.

Comment: Then the claim is not true: Let $A= \left\{ (1,1) \right\}$. Then $(x,y) \in A$ implies $x^2+y^4<4$, but there is no nontrivial open set contained in $A$.

Comment: I suspect that $A$ is defined by $\{ (x,y) | x^2 + y^4 \lt 4 \}$.

Comment: In that case clearly $B(0;1)  \subseteq A $

Comment: I am so sorry, my claim was ambiguous. There must exists an open disk centered at $(x,y)$ for every pair of $(x,y)$ inside A.

Comment: @hardmath: It is defined by $\{(x,y)|x^2+y^4<4\}$!

Comment: @MichaelDNguyen If that is the case, then note that your description of $A$ is not the same as this definition.

Comment: @M10687: You are right. I'm sorry for not doing a good job at stating this question. This is a subproblem in the problem I'm solving, and this is the first time I post some math-related question on math-stackexchange.

Comment: I guess that my general recommendation is to try drawing a picture. Maybe instead of finding an open disk, you can first find an open rectangle, then find an open disk inside the open rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a point $(u,v)\in A$ with $u\geq0$, $v\geq0$ be given. Then $$\rho:=4-u^2-v^4>0,\qquad u<2,\quad v<2\ .$$
We now determine an $h>0$ such that
$$(u+h)^2+(v+h)^4<4\ .$$
This $h$ has to satisfy
$$h\bigl(2u+h+4v^3+6v^2h+4vh^2+h^3\bigr)<4-u^2-v^4=\rho\ .$$ 
When $h\leq1$ then the large parenthesis is $$< 4+1+32+24 +8+1=70\ .$$
Since $\rho\leq4$ it follows that
$$h:={\rho\over70}<1$$
does the job: A square with side length $2h$ centered at $(u,v)$ is completely contained in $A$, and so is a disk with radius $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A  =D((0,0), 2)$. If $(p,q) \in A$, then $s:= d(p,q),(0,0)) < 2$, where $d$ denotes the Euclidean distance. So $r' = 2-s > 0$. Then the triangle inequality for $d$ implies that $B((p,q), r') \subseteq A$.

Comment: I suspect you want a square root somewhere...

Comment: I think there is something wrong with this solution. Considering $(p,q) /eq (0,0)$, then $r = 2$. So we could assume that $D((0,0),2) \subseteq A$, right? Let $(s,t)=(1.4, \sqrt(2))$ which is still inside D, $(s,t)$ is not an element of $A$. So it is not necessary that $D((p,q),r) \subseteq A$.

Comment: @MichaelDNguyen I was a bit too quick, I now wrote what I meant to say.

Comment: But $A \neq D((0,0),2)$. $(x,y)$ is inside $A$ iff $x^2+y^4<4$, not $x^2+y^2<4$.